# Detecting flash test player

Tags: actionscript, air, flash

I've noticed that there are certain AIR options that don't work in the flash test player (the one that previews movies when you Ctrl + enter).

One example is [NativeApplication.startAtLogin](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#startAtLogin).

If it is called from the standalone player (double clicking on the swf file, for example) it works, but if i test it on the flash ide it will throw an error.

Is there a way to detect if I'm testing the movie in the ide and so avoiding to use that property?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461923/detect-air-versus-flash-player-from-an-actionscript-library

Comment: Nearly: in the other question wasn't specified about the debug player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flash.system.Capabilities](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#playerType) has a property named playerType, which is set to "External" when using the test player and "Desktop" when using AIR. So,

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

...

if (Capabilities.playerType != 'External')
  // do stuff that don't work in the test player
if (Capabilities.playerType == 'Desktop')
  // do stuff that works only in AIR
```